# clear th existing drawn line and replace with the new line bezierpath

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I am using a `UIbezierpath` to draw for my Project. I am using colors to draw. When I draw on same points, the color becomes darken.(i.e drawing on the same place will normally). I want to maintain the brush color though on overwrite.

Any help will be appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try below method,

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),self.backgroundColor.CGColor);

    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect); // This line will clear your existing drawing

   // Line Drawing code
}
```

OR

```
UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, newSize}]; // newSize will be your size of the Eraser

[[UIColor clearColor] setFill];

[path fill];
```

Please refer this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit) as well to make paint and erase.

Thanks!

Comment: This fastly removes the existing line... User should not know that erasing

Comment: Also it removes the complete drawing

Comment: What should be the blend mode I should use?

Comment: You may use kCGBlendModeDestinationOut.

Comment: Hi How to maintain the rect of the bezierpath? becoz this clears nearer image too.....

Comment: You should adjust your Eraser brush size and position of the brush as well. Example : burshRect = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, brushWidth, brushHeight);;

Comment: Do you have any example ?

Comment: Yes, Did you see the link that i have add in my answer?

Comment: But I am not using this

Comment: Refer this link as well http://ashiphone.blogspot.in/2010/07/smooth-line-eraser-from-view.html